# Creating a CRUD using PHP + Bootstrap Modal + Mysql + JS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I need a page with a button to insert a new user, with fields "country","name" and "company". Then, in the same page, I need to list those datas and in front each item it'll appear two buttons, "edit" and "delete". At edit button, I need to display a Modal window (bootstrap), so I could update this data.
I hope someone could help me.
Thanks

Sorry, I've forgot to paste the code.

This is my **index.php**:

```
    <form action="inserir.php" method="post" name="visitas" id="visitas">
            <table class="table_geral" align="center" width="350" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">  
                <tr>
                    <td width="200">Pais:</td>
                    <td>
                        <?
                        $array_pais = array('Selecione...','Alemanha','Angola','Argentina','Bolívia','Brasil','Camarões','Canadá','Chile','China','Colombia', 
                                            'Costa Rica','Cuba','Dinamarca','Equador','Espanha','Estados Unidos','França','Holanda','Inglaterra','Itália','Japão', 
                                            'México','Nigéria','Panamá','Paraguai','Peru','Porto Rico','Portugal','Rússia','Senegal','Taiwan','Uruguai','Venezuela' 
                                            ); 
                        echo '<select class="form-control" style="width:330px" name="pais" id="pais">';
                        foreach($array_pais as $valor){
                            echo '<option>'.$valor.'</option>';
                        }
                        echo '</select>'; 
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td height="29" valign="center" align="center" rowspan="3">&nbsp </td>
                    <td height="29" valign="center" align="center" rowspan="3">
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value=" + ">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="411">Nome:</td>
                    <td width="339">
                        <input class="form-control" name="nome" type="text" id="nome" size="50">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="411">Empresa:</td>
                    <td width="339">
                        <input class="form-control" name="empresa" type="text" id="empresa" size="50" style="text-transform:uppercase;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_visitas ORDER BY empresa";
    $limite = mysql_query("$sql"); ?>       

 <table data-toggle="table" data-cache="false">
                    <thead align="center">
                        <tr height="35px" valign="center" bgcolor="#B0E2FF" >
                            <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width="100px">PAÍS</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width="250px">NOME</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width="300px">EMPRESA</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width="5px" colspan="2">AÇÕES</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <? while($result = mysql_fetch_array($limite)){ ?>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="display:none" align="center"><?=$result['id']; $_SESSION=$result['id'];?></td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:middle;"> <?=$result['pais']?></td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:middle;"> <?=$result['nome']?></td>
                            <td style="text-transform:uppercase; vertical-align:middle;"><?=$result['empresa']?></td>
                            <td style="width:20px">
                            <form action="editar.php" method="post">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Editar" href="editar.php?id=<?=$result['id'];?>"></a>
                            </form>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:20px">
                                <a class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" title="Deletar" href="deletar.php?id=<?=$result['id'];?>"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <?}?>
                </table>

<div class="container">
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Novo registro</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script>
        $('form').submit(function () {
           var postdata = {
               pais: $(this)[0].pais.value,
               nome: $(this)[0].nome.value,
               empresa: $(this)[0].empresa.value 
            }
            $.post("inserir.php", postdata, function (d) {
                $('#myModal').find(".modal-body").html(d);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

And it's my **inserir.php:**

```
<?
require("conexao.php");

    $pais = $_POST['pais'];
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $empresa = $_POST['empresa'];

    if (($pais == "") || ($pais == "Selecione...") || ($nome == "") || ($empresa == "")) { 
        echo "Favor preencha todos os campos!";
    } else {
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT nome FROM tb_visitas WHERE nome='$nome'");

        if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) { 
            echo "O nome <b>$nome</b> ja foi inserido na lista!";
        } else {
            $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO tb_visitas VALUES (null, '$pais', '$nome', UPPER('$empresa'))";
            mysql_query($sqlinsert) or die (mysql_error());
            echo "Gravado com sucesso!";
        }
    }       

?>
```

With assist from CodeGodie now I have this code, but I need to open a Modal window (bootstrap) to edit some register. However I don't know how to make it with AJAX. I feel sorry for my bad explanation and my English. Thanks

---

Sorry, but I'm beginner in php and ajax. There are much code that I've never seen :( ....Then, I'm having some difficulty to make it work out. I thought it was simplest. However I tried to make the files:

editar.php

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "visitas");

// Check connection
if (mysql_error()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error();
}

$id = $_POST['id'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
$pais = $_POST['pais'];


$query = "UPDATE tb_visitas SET nome = '$nome', empresa = '$empresa', pais= '$pais' WHERE id = $id ";

if (mysql_query($con, $query)) {
    $res['response'] = true;
    $res['message'] = "Record has been updated";
} else {
    $res['response'] = false;
    $res['message'] = "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysql_error($con);
}

echo json_encode($res);
```

deletar.php

```
<?php

require("conexao.php");

$id = $_POST['id'];

if  (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM tb_visitas WHERE id = $id";
    $deletar = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());        
}

?>
```

get_list.php

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "visitas");

if (mysql_error()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error();
}

$id = $_POST['id'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
$pais = $_POST['pais'];

$query  = "SELECT * FROM tb_visitas";


?>
```

conexão.php

```
<?

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$senha = '';
$banco = 'visitas';

$db = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $senha); 
mysql_set_charset('latin1',$db);
mysql_select_db($banco, $db) or die ("Não foi possível conectar ao banco MySQL");

?>
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried or do you want use to do all your homework for you? ;-)

Comment: Hi @netovgs, Can you please add some code to show what you have so far? If not this question might get closed.

Comment: As others have said - it's be helpful to see what you have so far... but, from what you've said, I'd think you want to be using AJAX to do your user adding, and then a sprinkle of jQuery to give you the modal window.

You could really do with reading this too: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You've just described your requirements.  What is your question?  What do you need help with?  Where are you stuck?  We're not here to do this for you or give you a step-by-step tutorial of the entire process.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you have now. Thanks for adding the code. I would first focus on design. It sounds like you want some sort of CRUD(Create Retrieve Update Delete) system. In that case, what I would do, is place the initial submission form on top (like what you have), and use modals to show any alert messages and the Edit form.

The design would look like this:

```
+-------------------------------------+
| Submit Form                         |
| - input                             |
| - input                             |
+-------------------------------------+
| List showing DB info                |
| - result 1 (with Edit/Delete links) |
| - result 2 (with Edit/Delete links) |
| ...                                 |
+-------------------------------------+
```

At page load, you will run an JS function, we can call it `update_list()`, that will use AJAX to fetch all the database info and parse it in the List container.

Then you will `delegate` Edit/Delete Click events to call the desired AJAX calls.

Keep in mind, this design structure separates everything in functions and uses AJAX to call on PHP scripts. The data will be sent via JSON.

Now, when you Submit the submission form, this will also use AJAX to send POST requests to PHP, then once submitted, JS will use Bootstrap's modal to show messages.

When the edit link is clicked, JS will again open a Bootstrap modal to show the edit form.

With that said, this is how I would do it :

```
<html>
    <title>Modal</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            #wrapper {
                padding: 10px;
            }

            .modal-header, h4, .close {
                background-color: #5cb85c;
                color: white !important;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 30px;
            }

            .modal-footer {
                background-color: #f9f9f9;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <form id="submit_form" role="form" style="width: 300px;">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pais">Pais:</label>
                    <?php
                    $array_pais = array('Selecione...', 'Alemanha', 'Angola', 'Argentina', 'Bolívia', 'Brasil', 'Camarões', 'Canadá', 'Chile', 'China', 'Colombia',
                        'Costa Rica', 'Cuba', 'Dinamarca', 'Equador', 'Espanha', 'Estados Unidos', 'França', 'Holanda', 'Inglaterra', 'Itália', 'Japão',
                        'México', 'Nigéria', 'Panamá', 'Paraguai', 'Peru', 'Porto Rico', 'Portugal', 'Rússia', 'Senegal', 'Taiwan', 'Uruguai', 'Venezuela'
                    );
                    echo '<select class="form-control" name="pais" id="pais">';
                    foreach ($array_pais as $valor) {
                        echo '<option>' . $valor . '</option>';
                    }
                    echo '</select>';
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="nome" type="text" id="nome" size="50">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="empresa">Empresa:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="empresa" type="text" id="empresa" size="50" style="text-transform:uppercase;">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="+">
            </form>


            <table id="list" class="table">
                <thead align="center">
                    <tr bgcolor="#B0E2FF">
                        <th>PAÍS</th>
                        <th>NOME</th>
                        <th>EMPRESA</th>
                        <th>AÇÕES</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div class="modals_container">
                <div class="modal fade" id="message_modal" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Message</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body"></div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal fade" id="edit_modal" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <form id="edit_form" class="form">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        Country: <input id="country_input" type="text" name="country">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        Nome: <input id="username_input" type="text" name="username">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        Company: <input id="company_input" type="text" name="company">
                                    </div>
                                    <input id="id_input" type="hidden" name="id">
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            function update_list() {
                $.getJSON("get_list.php", function (data) {

                    if (data.response) {
                        $("#list").find("tbody").empty();
                        data.results.forEach(function (i) {
                            console.log(i);
                            $("#list").find("tbody").append(
                                "<tr>" +
                                "<td>" + i.country + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + i.username + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + i.company + "</td>" +
                                "<td><a class='edit_link' href='" + JSON.stringify(i) + "'>edit</a> | <a class='delete_link' href='" + i.id + "'>delete</a></td>" +
                                "</tr>"
                            );
                        });
                    }

                });
            }
            update_list();
            $('#submit_form').submit(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "main.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.response) {
                            var $modal = $('#message_modal');
                            $modal.find(".modal-body").html(data.message);
                            $modal.modal('show');
                            update_list();
                        } else {
                            alert(data.message);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });

            $("#list").delegate('.edit_link', 'click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var info = JSON.parse($(this).attr("href"));
                var $modal = $("#edit_modal");
                $modal.find("#country_input").val(info.country);
                $modal.find("#company_input").val(info.company);
                $modal.find("#username_input").val(info.username);
                $modal.find("#id_input").val(info.id);
                $modal.modal('show');
            });

            $('#edit_form').submit(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "edit.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.response) {
                            var $modal = $('#message_modal');
                            $("#edit_modal").modal('hide');
                            $modal.find(".modal-body").html(data.message);
                            $modal.modal('show');
                            update_list();
                        } else {
                            alert(data.message);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

edit.php should be something like this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$id = $_POST['id'];
$nome = $_POST['username'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$country = $_POST['country'];


$query = "UPDATE table SET username = '$nome', company = '$company', country= '$country' WHERE id = $id ";

if (mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
    $res['response'] = true;
    $res['message'] = "Record has been updated";
} else {
    $res['response'] = false;
    $res['message'] = "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
}

echo json_encode($res);
```

Try this out, and let me know what you think.

Comment: Also dont hesitate in asking me if you need extra help. I can probably try to help you remotely as well. Let me know.

Comment: I'm implementing and testing, soon I'll post the result. But one question before, at 'edit.php' I put just sql code, right?

Comment: ok , i posted how edit.php should be like. Hopefully that gives you the right idea

Comment: Is my 'delete.php' correct? And 'get_list.php' I just need to make a select on database, right? Thks

Comment: yes, for `get_list.php`, all you have to do is SELECT all the info you need from the database. For `delete.php`, you need to make the PHP necessary to delete the item by `ID`

Comment: I've updated the post. Thanks.

Comment: Are you still having problems? What problems are you having now?

Comment: I've edited the post with files "editar.php", "deletar.php", "get_list.php", "inserir.php" and "conexao.php".

Comment: I see that but you need to explain what you dont understand or what does not work still

Comment: The records haven't been displayed. Maybe "get_list.php" is wrong. I put ../get_list.php on browser and it shows a right JSON list. But in index.php was empty.

Comment: do you want to work on this together remotely? perhaps using join.me or Teamviewer? I can help you faster like that. Let me know.

Comment: Could you do it? *.*

Comment: yes I can. How can i find you online so we can chat? do you have yahoo messenger?

Comment: Do you prefer to use skype, or my e-mail or it's unnecessary? Thks

Comment: yea skype works. what is your skype?

Comment: CodeGodie, I'm thankful for your assist. You've helped me a lot. God bless you.

Comment: Hello, I'm here again...lol...For my modal edit, how can I have a select instead of a text with countries in the options. And as selected item bring the record that I want to edit.
 $("#list").delegate('#edit_link', 'click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var info = JSON.parse($(this).attr("href"));
  var $modal = $("#editar_modal");
  $modal.find("#pais_input").val(info.pais);
  $modal.find("#nome_input").val(info.nome);
  $modal.find("#empresa_input").val(info.empresa);
  $modal.find("#id_input").val(info.id);
  $modal.modal('show');
    });

Comment: hey buddy. Can you create another question here on StackOverflow for this? Once you do that, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried but I'm blocked =( sorry

Comment: oh im sorry to hear that. Maybe try creating a new account or fixing that first so that we can helpy you through here.

Comment: I'll have to wait 3 days to create another post.

Comment: ouch.. well. I would load that list into the modal holding the SELECT, then with jquery you set that select to whatever value the country holds. Hard to explain.

Comment: Thanks Godie, I'll wait 3 days or creating a new account to open a new post. Hugs

Comment: Hey Codie, I've created a new user and post, following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783725/delete-selected-items-with-modal-confirmation-php Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've not changed much php code of yours. I added little code to it. 
In , i added code to call editar.php modal. In that script tag.. more code were there.. I don't know what is that.

**index.php**

```
//
Your original code here(No changes). From down, it started changing
//
<table data-toggle="table" data-cache="false">
    <thead align="center">
        <tr height="35px" valign="center" bgcolor="#B0E2FF" >
            <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width="100px">PAÍS</th>
            <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width="250px">NOME</th>
            <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width="300px">EMPRESA</th>
            <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width="5px" colspan="2">AÇÕES</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <? while($result = mysql_fetch_array($limite)){ ?>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none" align="center"><?=$result['id']; $_SESSION=$result['id'];?></td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle;"> <?=$result['pais']?></td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle;"> <?=$result['nome']?></td>
            <td style="text-transform:uppercase; vertical-align:middle;"><?=$result['empresa']?></td>
            <td style="width:20px">

            //Some Changes Here.. check it

            <a class='btnEdit' href="#form_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-EditID="<?echo $result['id'];?>">
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>
            <a>
            </td>
            <td style="width:20px">
                <a class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" title="Deletar" href="deletar.php?id=<?=$result['id'];?>"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <?}?>
</table>

//Add this code.
<div id="form_modal" class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

//Added few codes in script for calling modal.
<script>
    $('form').submit(function () {
       var postdata = {
           pais: $(this)[0].pais.value,
           nome: $(this)[0].nome.value,
           empresa: $(this)[0].empresa.value 
        }
        $.post("inserir.php", postdata, function (d) {
        $('#myModal').find(".modal-body").html(d);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
        return false;
    });
    $('.btnEdit').click(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr('data-EditID');
        $.ajax({url:"editar.php?id="+id,cache:false,success:function(result){
            $(".modal-content").html(result);
        }});
    });
</script>
```

Make One editar.php. Paste this below code in that page.
**editar.php**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Novo registro
    </h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" style='text-align:justify;'>
    <?echo $_GET['id'];?>   
    //Show Details Here.    
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for try to help 'Nana'.