# Delete selected Items with modal confirmation PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, modal-dialog

I have this **index.php** code:

```
<form role="form" id="submit_form" class="form-horizontal">

                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                      <label class="control-label">País</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <?
                        $array_pais = array('Selecione...', 'Alemanha', 'Angola', 'Argentina', 'Bolívia', 'Brasil', 'Camarões', 'Canadá', 'Chile', 'China', 'Colombia',
                            'Costa Rica', 'Cuba', 'Dinamarca', 'Equador', 'Espanha', 'Estados Unidos', 'França', 'Holanda', 'Inglaterra', 'Itália', 'Japão',
                            'México', 'Nigéria', 'Panamá', 'Paraguai', 'Peru', 'Porto Rico', 'Portugal', 'Rússia', 'Senegal', 'Taiwan', 'Uruguai', 'Venezuela'
                        );
                        echo '<select class="form-control" name="pais" id="pais">';
                        foreach ($array_pais as $valor) {
                            echo '<option>' . $valor . '</option>';
                        }
                        echo '</select>';
                        ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                      <label class="control-label">Nome:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Digite o nome">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <label class="control-label">Empresa</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">                 
                        <input id="empresa" name="empresa" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Digite a empresa">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset">

                        <div style="float:left; padding-right:30px">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" aria-label="Left Align">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Adicionar
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div style="float:right;">
                            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" onClick="parent.location='exibir.php'">
                        </div>                  
                    </div>  
                  </div>
                </div>

              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="jumbotron">
              <table data-toggle="table" data-cache="false" class="table" id="list">
                <thead align="center">
                  <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <th>PAÍS</th>
                    <th>NOME</th>
                    <th>EMPRESA</th>
                    <th>AÇÕES</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="modal fade" id="inserir_modal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>&nbsp; Inserir
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="modal fade" id="editar_modal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <form id="edit_form" class="form">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h3 class="modal-title">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>&nbsp; Editar
                        </h3>               
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">País:</label>
                            <input id="pais_input" name="nome" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Digite o pais">
                        </div>          
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Nome:</label>
                            <input id="nome_input" name="nome" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Digite a empresa">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Empresa:</label>
                            <input id="empresa_input" name="empresa" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Digite a empresa">
                        </div>
                        <input id="id_input" type="hidden" name="id">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" aria-label="Left Align">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Gravar
                        </button>

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="modal fade" id="deletar_modal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp; Exclusão
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  



<script>

    function update_list() {
        $.getJSON("get_list.php", function (data) {
            if (data.response) {
                $("#list").find("tbody").empty();
                data.results.forEach(function (i) {
                    $("#list").find("tbody").append(
                        "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + i.pais + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + i.nome + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + i.empresa + "</td>" +
                        "<td align='center'><a class='btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' title='Editar' id='edit_link' href='" + JSON.stringify(i) + "'></a> | <a class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash' title='Deletar' id='delete_link' href='"  + JSON.stringify(i) + "'></a></td>" +
                        "</tr>"
                    );
                });
            }
        });
    }

    $("#list").delegate('#edit_link', 'click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var info = JSON.parse($(this).attr("href"));
        var $modal = $("#editar_modal");
        $modal.find("#pais_input").val(info.pais);
        $modal.find("#nome_input").val(info.nome);
        $modal.find("#empresa_input").val(info.empresa);
        $modal.find("#id_input").val(info.id);
        $modal.modal('show');
    });

    update_list();
    $('#submit_form').submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "inserir.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.response) {
                  var $modal = $('#inserir_modal');
                  $modal.find(".modal-body").html(data.message);
                  $modal.modal('show');
                  update_list();
                } else {
                  alert(data.message);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    $('#edit_form').submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "editar.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.response) {
                    var $modal = $('#inserir_modal');
                    $("#editar_modal").modal('hide');
                    $modal.find(".modal-body").html(data.message);
                    $modal.modal('show');
                    update_list();
                } else {
                    alert(data.message);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }); 

</script>
```

**edit.php**

```
<?php
require('conexao.php');

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $pais = $_POST['pais'];
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $empresa = $_POST['empresa'];

    $query = "UPDATE tb_visitas SET nome = '$nome', empresa = '$empresa', pais= '$pais' WHERE id = $id ";
    $update = mysql_query($query);

        if ($update) {
            $res['response'] = true;
            $res['message'] = "Registro atualizado com sucesso!";
        } else {
            $res['response'] = false;
            $res['message'] = "Erro: " . $query . "<br>" . mysql_error();
        }

    echo json_encode($res);

    ?>
```

get_list.php

```
<?php

require('conexao.php');

    $sql = "SELECT id, pais, nome, empresa FROM tb_visitas";

    $table = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($table) > 0) {
        $res['response'] = true;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($table)) {
            $res['results'][] = $row;
        }
    } else {
        $res['response'] = false;
        $res['message'] = "Erro: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysql_error($con);
    }

    echo json_encode($res);

    ?>
```

**deletar.php**

```
<?php

require('conexao.php');

$id = $_POST['id'];

$query = "DELETE FROM tb_visitas WHERE id = $id ";

if (mysql_query($query)) {
    $res['response'] = true;
    $res['message'] = "Registro deletado com sucesso!";
} else {
    $res['response'] = false;
    $res['message'] = "Erro: " . $query . "<br>" . mysql_error($con);
}

echo json_encode($res);

?>
```

and **conexao.php**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$senha = '';
$banco = 'visitas';

$db = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $senha); 
mysql_set_charset('latin1',$db);
mysql_select_db($banco, $db) or die ("Não foi possível conectar ao banco MySQL");

?>
```

So, now I'd like to put a checkbox in each item for being able to select several records and delete them at once. Another question, when I edit a record if I put a text the field it's filled, but if I put a select it doesn't work. The idea is the select field has all options of countries and letting  that item from the record  already selected. I hope you understand what I need. Thanks.

Comment: It's better to ask one objective question at a time... say what is working and show where you got stuck

Comment: Actually whole that code is working, I wanna just improve it, with these questions. Thks

Comment: We understood what you need. Now it's time for you to understand [what to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what not to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) here in StackOverflow, and how to proceed after [taking the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Good luck!

Comment: To get better quality answers, you need to do some research, attempt yourself, then return if you get stuck or have a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you have two questions:

1. How to put checkboxes on your CRUD list in order to delete all items at once.

   It seems that you are using `update_list()` to load all items on your table. Since thats the case, you need to add an extra `<td>` in that row to that iteration with the checkbox element.

   ```
           data.results.forEach(function (i) {
               $("#list").find("tbody").append(
                   "<tr>" +
                   "<td><input class='item_checkbox' type='checkbox'/></td>" +
                   "<td>" + i.pais + "</td>" +
                   "<td>" + i.nome + "</td>" +
                   "<td>" + i.empresa + "</td>" +
                   "<td align='center'><a class='btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' title='Editar' id='edit_link' href='" + JSON.stringify(i) + "'></a> | <a class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash' title='Deletar' id='delete_link' href='"  + JSON.stringify(i) + "'></a></td>" +
                   "</tr>"
               );
           });
   ```

   Once you have that set, you can then use jquery to collect all checkboxes by class `.item_checkbox` and run a delete function.
2. How to make sure the SELECT country field is pre-selected when you EDIT an item

   Since you are using bootstrap modals, when you edit an item, that modal will popup showing that info. What you need to do is send that item's country ID to that modal's form so that it can be preselected, so do the following change:

   first in `#editar_modal`

   ```
   <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label">País:</label>
       <select id="pais_input" name="pais">
       <?php foreach ($array_pais as $pais) { ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $pais ?>"><?php echo $pais ?></option>
       <?php } ?>  
   </div>
   ```

   then in `'#edit_link', 'click', function (e)` add:

   ```
   $modal.find("#pais_input").val(info.pais);
   ```

Comment: Hi...the Select worked perfectly. And Delete I've tried some like that: `$(this).click(function() {
  var id = $('.item_checkbox:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
   return this.id;
  }).get();
  alert(id);
 }); ` and I've put it `"<td><input class='item_checkbox' id='" + i.id + "' type='checkbox'/></td>" + ` It creates an array but I'm not getting to send with ajax and delete the records. Damn it.

Comment: could help me again? Thks

Comment: I made work. ´<? require("conexao.php");
 if($_REQUEST['delete']) { $totalarray = sizeof($del);
  for($i=0; $i<$totalarray; $i++) {
   if(!empty($del[$i])){
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM tb_visitas WHERE id=".$del[$i]) or die(mysql_error()); } }
  $msg="Values Deleted Successfully";}
?>´

 `function CheckAll() {
  for (var i=0; i<document.frmDelSelected.elements.length; i++) { var e = document.frmDelSelected.elements[i];
   if (e.name != "allBoxes")
    e.checked = document.frmDelSelected.allBoxes.checked;
  } } ` I wanted to make the way you did, using ajax, but it didn't work for me. =(

Comment: you are using the jquery library, therefore it would be better for you to use its functions.. You are using `document.frmSelected`than iterating, where with jquery all you would need to do is apply events to all by class name.. wanna do a Teamviewer session?

Comment: For me, great...929 238 508 - 6299

Comment: Thank you CodeGodie, helped me a lot again. Hugs.